# How should I have flagged this?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174545/need-help-understanding-jquery-code) as VLQ.

The OP admits copy-pasting chunks of code, and asks more experienced jQuerians to explain his pastings to him.

All viewers of the question appear to express distaste, twice DV's (not incl. me) and comments left to that effect.

My profile shows that my flag was 'disputed', however, and the question remains open.

So my question is, assuming we are in agreement that this is a poor question, what should I have done differently, was VLQ the wrong flag in this case? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That post didn't really need to be flagged at all. Here's the text that accompanies the VLQ flag:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Only flag posts as VLQ when no sense can be made of them. This isn't a good question, but it isn't keyboard mashing gibberish either. Downvoting and voting to close suffice.

Comment: And what should I do until I have the 3k rep necessary to vote to close? Just downvote?

Comment: @OllieFord Yes, and/or comment if you think the author can improve the question.

Comment: @OllieFord You can also flag it, with the flag -> it should be closed for another reason option. That doesn't count as a vote to close, but it puts it in a review queue.